# How to replace a variable URL string (inside <img src="">) depending on pattern? (SimplePie)

Tags: php, facebook, rss, simplepie

This is my first post here. I'm not sure if the title of my post is the most descriptive way of showing my problem, sorry in advance!

Anyway, I've got a Facebook RSS feed on my site using simplepie - I'm displaying posts with a brief summary of its content and an accompanying image, both coming from the feed itself.

I've got a single div that displays this information and is repeated according to the number of stories I've set to display, in my case 3, so the HTML page outputs three div's each with a different story/accompanying image.

```
<div class="block">
<a href="<?php echo $image_url ?>" target="_blank">
<img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
```

The problem is Facebook RSS feeds only show tiny thumbnails generated from the original image (either external or from Facebook's server), but I want them in their original resolution.

I've succesfully replaced the thumbnails coming from Facebook's server by changing the name of the image (from "something_s.jpg" to "something_n.jpg"):

```
$image = str_replace("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg", $image);
```

I tried with **ltrim** to remove the Facebook URL appended before the external image's URL (e.g. https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDZORAaPpbr5COr&w=154&h=154&url=http://example.com/image.jpg). So, I thought this would do it:

```
$image = ltrim(stristr(str_replace("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg", $image), '&url='), '&url=');
```

Oddly enough, external images showed up in their original resolution (e.g. example.com/image.jpg inside `<img src="">`) but those coming from Facebook (e.g. 10153970_10153145169383306_1966565627_n.jpg) did not anymore. The img src attribute is just empty!

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

(BTW, this is simplepie code in my page):

```
<?php
require_once('../php/autoloader.php'); 
$feed = new SimplePie();

$feed->set_feed_url(array('https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=40796308305'));

$feed->set_item_limit(3);
$feed->init();

function returnImage ($text) {
$text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$pattern = "/<img[^>]+\>/i";
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
$text = $matches[0];
return $text;
}

function scrapeImage($text) {
$pattern = '/src=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)[\'" >]/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $link);
$link = $link[1];
$link = urldecode($link);
return $link;
}

$feed->strip_htmltags(array('embed','center','strong'));

$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
$feedDescription = $item->get_content();
$image = returnImage($feedDescription);
$image = scrapeImage($image);
$image = ltrim(stristr(str_replace("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg", $image), '&url='), '&url=');
$image_url= $item->get_permalink();
$description = $item->get_description();
$description = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $description);
endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: Added a bit more info at the end of the post regading my SimplePie code.

Answer (score -1):

Mr.Rod

use this custom function to change Image src Attribue..

```
<?php
  function ChangeImageSrc($image , $Newsrc){
   $regex = '#src="(([^"/]*/?[^".]*\.[^"]*)"([^>]*)>)#';

    $Content = preg_replace($regex, $image, 'src="'.$Newsrc.'"');   
    return $Content;
   }
    // Useage
   $markup = "<img src='fb.com/blahblah.jpg'>";
   // Change Src
  $toNewSrc = ChangeImageSrc($markup , 'http://example.com/newsrc.png');
  print $toNewSrc;
?>
```

after adding this function to your script

change this line

```
$image = ltrim(stristr(str_replace("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg", $image), '&url='), '&url=');
```

to

```
$image = ChangeImageSrc('src="_n.jpg"', '_s.jpg');
```

you have to more customize this function to match your needs .

Comment: I'm gonna try this and comment later on!

Comment: That didn't work. Now I'm not even getting the images showing up. The src atrribute just returns a "_s.jpg" value.

Comment: have you copied the function as it is ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same function without alterations.

Comment: then it should return this string src='newsource.jpg' .

Comment: Nevermind. I ended up using regular expressions to replace the appended URL. First time using them today, actually!

Comment: i think your not printing the returned value .. use echo or print